# Google Chrome: How to select text with touchscreen?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, google-chrome, touchscreen

Is it possible to select (and copy after that of course) any text on web page using fingers and touchscreen?

I found only one opportunity - double tap selects single word under tap point. But I need to select more that one word!

IE10 works nice with selection, but Chrome do not? Google had missed that point?

Using Chrome 24.0.1312.57, Windows 8 Pro x86, touchscreen with two points.

Comment: In Win8, are you using the Desktop or Metro version of Chrome? (Are you using Win7 with a touchscreen too?)

Comment: Using Desktop version. Metro sucks - it does not even starts in my tablet (1024x600). No Win7 ATM, but I think this does not matter.

Comment: I asked about Win7 because you added the tag. As for Metro, you don't have the minimum resolution required (1024x768, 1366x768 for snapping Metro apps).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this idea from [List of Touchscreen + Google Chrome Problems](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/EulUbpzyJ1A) :

1. click on the start of the text that you want to select
2. press & hold the shift key
3. click the end of the text that you want to select

Comment: Accepted. However, it is no need in "double click". 1. Click on start point; 2. hold shift; 3. click on end point.

Comment: Weird! **Keyboard** required for text selection on **tablet-pc**!

Comment: I fixed the answer. This keyboard method exists since (I think) Windows 95. It's Chrome's fault if it doesn't have a better one.

Comment: +1 because this is the only method, but really disappointed with the Chrome experience on a Win8 tablet, so different from the flawless Android version.

Answer (score 2):

For Chrome: long press a location on your screen in you will get a selection highlight with two little dots or flags at either end of the text you have selected.  Drag these with your finger until everything you want is selected.  Long press again for the operations you want to perform

Comment: True for the latest Chrome version.

Answer (score 2):

Hold CTRL + long tap on world will select it

Answer (score 1):

Have tried to copy and paste the way you would on Chrome for android?

Long hold touch until 2 brackets appear, then spread the bracket to encompass the selection.

I don't have a touch device with windows so this is just a guess.

Comment: Miss. On Windows platform - long tap (hold touch) is equivalent to RightClick. That is long tap immediately shows page context menu (Back, Reload, SaveAs, ...)

Answer (score 1):

This works on a windows 8 touchscreen laptop in Chrome.

Tap twice: highlight 1 word. 
Tap three times: highlight row. 
Tap twice, pause, tap once on highlighted word: drag out beginning and end of highlights.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, it seems Chrome can only see the touch events when using Wayland (under X11 it just sees touches as mouse clicks). To enable that, go to `chrome://flags` and change "Preferred Ozone Platform" to "Wayland", and make sure you're using a WM that supports Wayland (like KDE).